# click button in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, click

[html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MEww.png)[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TofAj.png)
how can click buton in this html code im using selenium.

I'm trying to writing a loop in my admin panel.

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to include your code as **text** rather than as screenshot(s)? On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first off that button does not have an `id='button'`

without seeing the website you could try do something like:

```
login_button = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'button')
login_button.click() # this assumes that there are no other buttons on the page as find_element finds the first button on the page
```

OR

```
login_button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'btn')
login_button.click() # this assumes that there are no other elements with the `btn` class to click
```

Comment: Thank you so much 2nd one worked <333